# Binding C to Crystal: preprocessor directives

Tags: c, crystal-lang

I'm working with the `crt.cr` Crystal shard, which binds ncurses. It's lacking some things I want, like `mvhline()`. So I'm adding the things I want.

One thing I want is is ncurses alternative character sheet, so I can make nice boxes.

As far as I can tell, this is pretty dang hard (but I'm not an expert in either Crystal or C). [From what I can tell, the alternative character sheet characters are all unsigned chars, defined by the preprocessor.](https://github.com/gittup/ncurses/blob/5a58bcb99470378fbbb24d21cb5e54f08cb7d353/include/curses.h.in#L234)

Can someone explain how I can get access to the alternative character sheet characters?

Comment: This sounds a bit too broad for the site - but awesome for the [developers list](https://crystal-lang.org/community)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: Sorry - I mean the question seems to be offtipic for the site, for being too broad, but you could get some help asking at Crystal's mailing list

Comment: Which site is "the site"? Sorry, I'm not following.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot access things that are only in C header files (and things that are done through the preprocessor) in a shared library file, because they simply aren't put there.

Since Crystal only binds to a shared library file, there is no option other than manually (sometimes [automatically](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal_lib)) duplicating these as constants in Crystal code.

Comment: Yep, that's what I did.