# Referencing C enums in a Crystal lib

Tags: crystal-lang

I'm trying to write a Crystal wrapper around `libevent`, and I wondered how to approach its enums that are named as all lower-case, for instance:

enum [ev_http_request_error](http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-2.1/doxygen/html/http_8h.html#a01f921a909d1504f873222b1d29c2b4a):

I tried the following:

```
@[Link("event")]
lib LibEvent
  # <snip>
  enum evhttp_request_error
    EVREQ_HTTP_TIMEOUT,
    EVREQ_HTTP_EOF,
    EVREQ_HTTP_INVALID_HEADER,
    EVREQ_HTTP_BUFFER_ERROR,
    EVREQ_HTTP_DATA_TOO_LONG
  end
end
```

but this fails because `evhttp_request_error` doesn't fit the grammar for a Crystal constant. 
How should I address this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can name it whatever you want. But when you use [`enum`](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/c_bindings/enum.html) inside your lib wrapper, you just declare a new C enum:

```
@[Link("event")]
lib LibEvent
   enum EvHTTPRequestError
     EVREQ_HTTP_TIMEOUT
     EVREQ_HTTP_EOF
     EVREQ_HTTP_INVALID_HEADER
     EVREQ_HTTP_BUFFER_ERROR
     EVREQ_HTTP_DATA_TOO_LONG
  end
end
```

This is effectively the same as:

```
@[Link("event")]
lib LibEvent
   enum EvHTTPRequestError
     EVREQ_HTTP_TIMEOUT = 0
     EVREQ_HTTP_EOF = 1
     EVREQ_HTTP_INVALID_HEADER = 2
     EVREQ_HTTP_BUFFER_ERROR = 3
     EVREQ_HTTP_DATA_TOO_LONG = 4
  end
end
```

and the values in this enum will not match the values from your original C lib.

You need to [set (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43693365/1586762) correct values manually in your enum.

> Since Crystal only binds to a shared library file, there is no option other than manually (sometimes automatically) duplicating these as constants in Crystal code.

[Checkout example in Crystal stdlib](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/b86bb3a3cd949362c4db126766e83569063cf725/src/event/lib_event2.cr#L25-L39)

Answer (score 1):

In short, [it doesn't matter](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/4877#issuecomment-324266308). The name doesn't need to be an exact match to the C name (it's a glorified int anyway), so provided the *values* match their counterparts in C-land, Crystal's name for that type can be whatever you want :)